# Take CSV file from HTML form and create a table in sqllite in django

Tags: python, html, django, sqlite

Right now I've tried using pandas and converting the file into json and then creating a table with it.

This my code

**HTML File**

```
  <body>
    <form action="upload/" method="post" enctype="multipart/formdata">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="block has-text-centered">
        <h3
          class="is-size-3 has-text-centered is-family-primary has-text-success-dark"
        >
          Upload a CSV File
        </h3>
        <div class="file is-medium has-name is-info is-centered" id="csv-file">
          <label class="file-label">
            <input class="file-input" type="file" name="csv" accept=".csv" />
            <span class="file-cta">
              <span class="file-icon">
                <i class="fas fa-upload"></i>
              </span>
              <span class="file-label">
                Choose a file…
              </span>
            </span>
            <span class="file-name">
              No file uploaded
            </span>
          </label>
        </div>
        <br />
        <input
          class="button is-outlined is-rounded is-info"
          type="submit"
          value="Submit"
        />
        <input
          class="button is-outlined is-rounded is-info"
          type="reset"
          value="Reset"
          id="csv-reset"
        />
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**VIEWS File**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'results/home.html', {})
```

**CSV LOGIC (csvviews.py)**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import pandas as pd
from django.contrib import messages

def form_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.FILES.get(u'csv')
        df = pd.read_csv(file)
        df.to_json(turned_json)
        my_obj = CsvModel.objects.create(csv_file=turned_json)
        my_obj.save()
    messages.success(request, 'CSV Uploaded!')
    return render(request, 'results/home.html')
```

**MODELS File**

```
from django.db import models

class CsvModel(models.Model):
    csv_file = models.FileField()
```

**URLS File**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views,csvviews

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name="HOME"),
    path('upload/', csvviews.form_page, name='UPLOAD'),
]
```

But using this code I'm getting the following error

[ERROR IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRTuj.png)

**Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'NoneType'>**

How do I solve this? Are there any specific packages for csv in django? Is there an easier way?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post the full error, as it will assist with knowing which line it is on. Where does `turned_json` get set? Also, do you want to create a new table for each time this form gets submitted? What do you want to name the table?

Comment: @AMG

If I'm not wrong....then turned_json is set for csv_field which is defined in django models.py and Yes a new table has to be created and it has to be named uniquely everytime

Comment: this line `df.to_json(turned_json)` is likely your first thing to tackle. See examples at: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html. You probably want to start with `turned_json = df.to_json()`. Which sqllite database do you want to store the tables in, same one as Django models or another one?

Comment: @AMG I have added error image hope you can help...I want to store in the same django models database and also I changed the code still getting the same error

Comment: There could be a lot going on. You don't appear to be using Django forms, but I'd suggest you do, then use the is_valid function to determine if you are getting a file where you think you are. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads

Answer (score 0):

You are converting your file to JSON data. And you are trying to add JSON data to a FileField.

---

- **For Django 3**

**Just convert your** `models.FileField()` **to** `models.JSONField()`.

```
from django.db import models

class CsvModel(models.Model):
    csv_file = models.JSONField()
```

---

- *For < Django 1.9*

Install jsonfield to add a JSON field to your model.

```
pip install jsonfield
```

Change your models.py like this:

```
from django.db import models
import jsonfield

class CsvModel(models.Model):
    csv_file = jsonfield.JSONField()
```

Note:

If you have a problem with this package just convert your `models.FileField()` to `models.TextField()`. Because JSON data is actually a text.

Comment: I'm using Django 4 and I've tried your code I'm still getting the same error....the error is on line 8 of csvviews.py file